# Display dialog from command line (like xmessage does)

Tags: macos, command-line, script, dialog

## Background

I'd like to be able to display a notification window in OS X from within a script. The script will be running in background, so the notification should not go to the terminal but instead be displayed in a dialog window.

## What I found so far

### xmessage

On Linux I'd probably use `xmessage` or one of its variants for this. But on OS X, starting the bulky X server just for this task seems both overkill and too slow for my taste.

### Finder dialog

I've found a similar question in [this forum thread](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=42616), where the “accepted” reply suggested this command:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Hey!"'
```

But on my OS X [10.7](/questions/tagged/10.7), the resulting dialog isn't displayed immediately. Instead, the Finder icon starts to bounce, and the dialog becomes visible only after I click on the icon. Too many mouse clicks, too disruptive.

### Notifier

There is an [answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/345455/144771) which suggests a tool called [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier). Unfortunately that appears to only work for OS X [10.8](/questions/tagged/10.8), so it won't help in my case.

## Question

So is there some tool, either included in OS X [10.7](/questions/tagged/10.7) or freely available, which allows displaying a small dialog to the user without too much overhead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to tell a background process like SystemUIServer to display the dialog:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "SystemUIServer"
display dialog "message"
end
activate application (path to frontmost application as text)'
```

You can also tell the frontmost application to display a dialog, but it's not shown immediately if the application is not responding. If MPlayer OS X is frontmost, text dialogs don't accept any keyboard input.

```
osascript -e 'tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
display dialog "message"
end'
```

Comment: The first approach has the drawback that it will raise *all* windows of the given application, which I find slightly annoying. But the second approach is the best I've seen so far. Apps not responding should be rare enough that I won't worry about these.

Answer (score 3):

Try

`tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Plug the Digispark into the USB port." buttons {"OK"} with icon caution`

Tested on OS X 10.8.2

Comment: Sounds like I need to learn osascript

Comment: Question: Adding the clause `buttons {"OK"}` causes the dialog to not get focus when it pops up. Leaving it out gives you a Cancel button, which we don't want, but at least the dialog gets focus. Is there a way to get focus, even when using that clause?