# Send notification from command line

Tags: macos, command-line, notifications, script

On Mac OS X, some applications will display a notification that appears briefly in the upper-right corner (e.g., when I receive email).

Is there a way to generate a notification from the command-line?  In other words, is there a command-line program I can run to display a custom notification, with text of my choice?  Ideally, I'd love to be able to run something like

```
show-notification "Hello world!"
```

from a shell script and have a notification appear showing the text "Hello world!".

---

I discovered I can use [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83359/24154) to display a dialog box in the center of the screen that the user has to click "OK" on, but I'm looking for a notification not a modal dialog box.

Answer (score 20):

The following works:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Hello world!" with title "Hi!"'
```